Scenario | Portfolio optimization
Can someone explain to me what exactly is a portfolio scenario? Is it a range of historical returns over some date range for N assets or just single historical returns vector of each N assets? Or does it vary with different methods?
For example I want to optimize portfolio over T=100 "scenarios" with algorithm from this article (page 51). Is a single scenario just taking a mean of historical returns for every assets over certain period of time? I don't get it. And do it for every "scenario" (different date ranges)?
